# Can I upgrade my system to Focal Fossa Ubuntu 20.04 if I only have 3.9 GB of RAM?

Tags: upgrade

Bellow are my system specifications:

```
    root@linux-pc:~# tlp stat -s
    --- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

    System         = Apple Inc. 1.0 MacBookAir5,2
    BIOS           = 261.0.0.0.0
    Release        = Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
    Kernel         = 5.4.0-70-generic #78~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 14:10:07 UTC          2021 x86_64
    /proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-  root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
    Init system    = systemd v237
    Boot mode      = UEFI 

    root@linux-pc:~# free
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:        3934556     2081136      113232      484632     1740188     1105676
    Swap:        999420       11008      988412
```

According to the Ubuntu community help wiki (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) the following specifications are required:

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- **4 GiB RAM (system memory)**
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD     for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

**Will 3.9GB meet the requirement or cause issues in the future? Thanks!**

Comment: The installer won't refuse to install. However, we have not tested with 3.9GB, so we don't know if you will encounter any problems. Seems like you are offering to do that testing, so let us know.

Comment: I use devices with as little as 2GB to test releases (using 1GB up to 19.04 for *flavors*), but with 2GB of RAM you'll need to consider how you do things (I do with 4GB too actually), matching your apps with the desktop you're using, what's sharing RAM etc. Yes it'll run, but the experience will be less especially if you're not careful with how you use the machine. It'll really depend how you use it, and how much you plan/think about your apps before you load them (ie. consider how they'll use the RAM; do you consider that? if you don't you'll need more RAM)

Comment: FYI:  The specs you list applied to all releases from (& including) 17.10 where GNOME was the default; so if you are using 18.04 currently, those are the minimum recommended specifications for 18.04 too.  The current specs were made by 2019-10-14 19:47:03 Will Cooke (then head of Ubuntu Desktop) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements?action=info; where you'll note 2GB was the 17.04 recommended minimum; so upgrade from what? either of 18.04 or 19.10 that upgraded to 20.04 were both 4GB recommended minimum)

Comment: That is a really good point @guiver

Comment: That is a good point @guiverc. I will consider the requirements to be recommendations and be sure to manage my RAM carefully (if that is even necessary). Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to run Ubuntu with a system that reports slightly less than 4GiB.

The page you link uses jargon: In this case the "recommended minimum system requirements" are just *recommended* minimum system specifications. The term "requirement" is somewhat misleading but is the common term used.

This is hinted at in the line:

> "A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista,
> Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu
> even if they are lower-spec than described below."

Your system, if those specs are right, is what's known as 4GiB too, for what it's worth.

The links on this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir5-2 may help, although they refer to older versions of the Ubuntu distro; if anything things should work better.

Comment: I'm interested in what you consider could be improved.... Are you a wiki editor?  If you'd like to try and re-write bits you think should be written more newbie friendly, let me know (even if you're not a wiki editor).

Comment: It's really hard guiverc, "system requirements" is jargon was really what I meant. Getting the balance right is hard because people will use that as a search term; but it will inevitably confuse newbies. I'm not sure it should be more newbie friendly though! ;o) I've made a minor edit.